# What is the fastest way of summing set bits in Ruby's NArray?

Tags: ruby, bit, narray

I used NArray to implement a bit array, but I am not quite satisfied with the speed of the bits_on method. Currently I have:

```
# Method that returns the number of bits set "on" in a bit array.
def bits_on
  bits_on = 0

  self.byte_array.each do |byte|
    bits_on += @count_array[byte]
  end

  bits_on
end
```

`byte_array` is an NArray.byte() type, and `@count_array` is build like this:

```
# Method that returns an array where the element index value is
# the number of bits set for that index value.
def init_count_array
  count_array = []

  (0 ... (2 ** BitsInChar)).each do |i|
    count_array << bits_in_char(i)
  end

  count_array
end
```

Ideas?

Cheers,

Martin

Comment: Could someone please add a "narray" tag. I am not allowed.

Comment: A lookup table like that should be one of the faster approaches. Just how much data are you processing here? This is something that could be made parallel or, if you're really stuck, implemented as a C extension to Ruby.

Comment: So if there is no obvious way to improve this in Ruby using the NArray interface, I shall contact the NArray developer next. Perhaps with a little patch?

Comment: You might want to use Benchmark to create a baseline with just your addition routine, and one with the NArray component to see if this is an NArray problem or a Ruby problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the background correctly, a possible solution is:

```
def bits_on
  NArray.to_na(@count_array)[self.byte_array].sum
end
```

---

Sorry, the above is wrong, the next will work:

```
def bits_on
  index = NArray.int(*self.byte_array.shape)
  index[] = self.byte_array
  NArray.to_na(@count_array)[index].sum
end
```

Comment: Hm, this seems to be wrong: self.size(=256) != mask.size(=2048) (TypeError)

Comment: Yours is bits_on2 in the benchmark -> http://pastie.org/2716109. Really nice. Now I just need to get my head around what is actually going on?

Comment: One thing I dont like is that an integer array array is created with the same number of elements as the byte array - that is x times larger. The whole idea with bit arrays is that you store as much information in a byte array as possible because of memory restrictions.

Comment: If byte_array is defined by NArray.sint, which is 2-byte integer type, it occupies only twice of 1-byte NArray.byte type, and the upper solution works.

Comment: Right, sint. Now I was playing with the idea of a comparison with a Inline C version. This works if the @byte_array is a string, but I have no idea what to do with a NArray object. I'm looking into that. http://pastie.org/2716864